# AvAudioPlayer with option to play in background

Tags: objective-c, background, avaudioplayer

hello  I am trying to make an app, with a "switch" where it can set that AvAudioPlayer object will play or not  audiofile in backgorund.
Does exist  a way to change this mode, in oder to choose as option to play an audiofile with AvAudioplayer in background?
I mean Pragrammatically and then during RUNTIME.

Thanks so much for you help
( and clear explanation )

Comment: this will answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14760370/change-uibackgroundmodes-audio-at-runtime

Comment: Thank for your help, but this does not solve the problem.